# I'm trying to make a simple app that randomly changes the color of the body's background but all I'm getting on the emulator is a blank

Tags: flutter

I don't get any errors upon running, I just get a blank page. I guess it has to do with the layout arrangement, but that's just a guess.

I switched the class to `statful` in the scaffold body, so I can use `setState(){}` under the `flatButton`. I don't know why nothing is showing on the screen though, because I would assume at least the `AppBar` would be on the screen. Can the body extend over the `AppBar`?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
int colorNumber = 1;


void main()=> runApp(StructureBuild());

  class StructureBuild extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Random Color Generator',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
            body: BodyBuild()
        ));
  }
}



class BodyBuild extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyBuildState createState() => _BodyBuildState();
}

class _BodyBuildState extends State<BodyBuild> {
  int changeColor(int colorNumber) {
    return colorNumber = Random().nextInt(245) + 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(child:
      FlatButton(color: Color(colorNumber),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            changeColor(1);
          });
        }, child: Text('press anywhere'),));
  }
}
```

Comment: from where the int get color?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend checking the documentation of Flutter for using color const. Color const has color from the lower 32 bits of an int. 1-255 values are very rare values for Color. I suggest you find a hexadecimal value by examining the link I gave. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html .

Also, you can give an integer value. But it should be a huge number to change the color of the Flatbutton. For Example, 4123423412341242342 would change to color kind of turquoise blue.